# Android webview with timer

Tags: java, android, webview, timer

I am implementing a timer on webview activity with 1 second delay like clock. On each event webview is loaded with generated HTML having canvas and 2 tables.
With each tick, webview regenerate html and display content. As soon as I start scroll to go down, it starts scrolling auto and behaves erratically and moves up and down.
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your knowledge sharing. This issue was solved after 5 days by following countermeasures:

1. Splitting html into different divs and script tags.
2. Replacing full html mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL with
   String updateScript +=    "var                     mydiv=document.getElementById('div1');";
   updateScript += "var    oldScript=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];";
   updateScript +=  "var newScript = document.createElement('script');";
   updateScript += "mydiv.innerHTML= textStr;";
   updateScript += "newScript.innerHTML = scrStr;";
   updateScript += "document.body.appendChild(newScript);";
   updateScript += "oldScript.remove();";

mWebView.loadurl("javascript:" + updateScript);
on handler event.

Thanks